# How can I draw the box to show more detail as shown in the picture below?

Tags: latex, tikz

I couldn't find the way how to make that kind of box. Could anybody here help me? How to make this kind of box? Thanks
[Please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMqtq.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at section `71.7 Callout Shapes` from the tikz documentation

Comment: And have a look at the tikzmark library to position your callout shapes anywhere in a page.